# Get all the points on a straight line for technical analysis?

Tags: python

I want to plot trendlines on a price chart and then make sure that no price is touching it. For this I would need all the points which would be on the straight line chart. The inputs here would be 2 values ( 2 swing high values)
Kindly suggest how to calculate all the points on this straight line ? So lets say I have drawn this line between 2 points. Now I want to get all the points which are falling on this line.

[image]

Comment: I'm having trouble parsing what your question is about; could you expand with examples and if necessary, an image or two that explain what you're looking for? This might be more of a mathematical question than a programming one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no dicretization of either axis, there are an infinite number of points on any line between any two non identical points - so the question as asked perhaps isn't a practical method.

Suppose you have two known points `(x1, y1)` and `(x2, y2)` and you then want to apply a test to check that no other points lie below the line drawn through these points (as pictured in question).

I'd recommend first getting the gradient and intercepts of this line, i.e. `m` and `c` of the line equation `y = mx + c`. These can be calculated as:

`m = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)`, and then
`c = y1 - m*x1`

Finally for any point to be checked: `(x_test, y_test)`, you can check if they are above the line, as required, by checking: `y_test > m*x_test + c` which will return a boolean `True` if, and only if, the test point is above the line.